# How to nest rules in Less for defining class behaviour

Tags: css, less

I have written the following rules in Less. The aim is to have `span` in bold, and a color depending on the class applied to it:

```
span {
    font-weight: bold;
    .cheapest { color: green; }
    .expensive { color: red; }
}
```

The impacted text correctly applies the bold rule, but the color rules are not applied. I see in Visual Studio that this is compiled into the following CSS:

```
 span .cheapest {
  color: #00ff00;
 }
span .expensive {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

The space between element and class is like applying the colors to **elements with the *cheapest* or *expensive* class that are child of span**, which is not what I want.

I there a way in Less to correctly describe what I want? Obviously I could get rid of the nesting and repeat the span selector, but that would defeat one of the greatest features of Less. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
span {
    font-weight: bold;
    &.cheapest { 
    color: green; 
    }
    &.expensive { 
    color: red; 
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
span.cheapest {
  color: green;
}
span.expensive {
  color: red;
}
```

You can read about the `&` combinator [here](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules).